# Git - Azure DevOps UI - Feature Branch Name Case Sensitive

Tags: git, azure-devops

This is my current feature branch naming convention -

```
Feature/<UniqueId>-<ShortDescription> 
or
Feature/<ShortDescription>
```

If we create the new branch from Azure DevOps UI then because branch names are case sensitive - I may end up having branches something like this -

```
Feature
   feature1
   feature2
feature
   feature3
```

When we create branches using Git commands and Visual Studio Team Explorer - in both these, it  works just fine by treating branch names as case insensitive.
It's only with Azure DevOps UI that it treats 'Feature' and 'feature' as different.

So, I tried using [tf permission commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/git-permission-command?view=azure-devops).

It works fine for branch folder - so I can enforce branches to be created under a specific folder - which is "Feature" in my case.

However I realised that I have no control over branches being created as -

```
Feature
   feature1
   Feature1
   feature2
```

Anyone can please guide how can I create case insensitive branch names using Azure Devops UI.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: While *Git* treats branch names as case-sensitive, it sometimes *stores* those names as OS-level file or folder names, and some OSes treat those as case-*in*sensitive. If you ever use such OSes, you'll regret using mixed case. As a general rule, no branch should ever use any uppercase in its name, to avoid stumbling over this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `Case enforcement`

[image]

The result:

[image]

Check the additional documentation: [Git Cross-Platform Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/os-compatibility?view=azure-devops)

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply - any idea why I can't see images? could it be some internal work place security?

Comment: @inutan, I do not why you can not see images. However, you can find how to enable `Case enforcement` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#case-enforcement-policy